# "Service Injection" of Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

About "Service Injection",Documentation says:    https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#service-injection

> ## Service Injection
>
> The @inject directive may be used to retrieve a service from the Laravel service container. The first argument passed to @inject is the name of the variable the service will be placed into, while the second argument is the class / interface name of the service you wish to resolve:

```
@inject('metrics', 'App\Services\MetricsService')
<div>
    Monthly Revenue: {{ $metrics->monthlyRevenue() }}.
</div>
```

## My code:

1、Service:
NameAndRole.php

```
class NameAndRole
{
    public function nameAndRole() {
        $user = \Auth::user();
        $username= $user->name;
        $role =$user->getRoles();
        $slug=$role[0]['slug'];
        return compact('username','slug');
    }
}
```

2、view:
sidebar.blade.php

```
@inject('nameAndRole','App\Services\NameAndRole')
<div>
  <h4 >username：{{$username}}</h4>
  <h4>slug：{{$slug}}</h4>
</div>
```

**error:**

```
Undefined variable: username (View: D:\wnmp\www\laravel-book\resources\views\partials\sidebar.blade.php) (View: D:\wnmp\www\laravel-book\resources\views\partials\sidebar.blade.php)
```

Comment: Undefined variable what? There was no name specified in the error for the variable that was undefined?

Comment: As explained in the docs **"The first argument passed to @inject is the name of the variable the service will be placed into, while the second argument is the class / interface name of the service you wish to resolve"**.  So the `@inject` syntax as you use it now will create an instance of the `App\Services\NameAndRole` class and assign it to a variable named `nameAndRole`. If you were to call `{{ $nameAndRole->nameAndRole() }}` that will return an array with the username and slug as you're returning it from the `nameAndRole` method. There's no `username` and `slug` vars defined anywhere.

Comment: You might be misunderstanding how to use service injection in views, or maybe you might need a new approach, so please explain what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer on laracasts.com, I think this is what I want:

```
class NameAndRole
{
    public $username;
    public $slug;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $user = \Auth::user();
        $this->username = $user->name;
        $role = $user->getRoles();
        $this->slug = $role[0]['slug'];
    }
}
```

And in the Blade view:

```
@inject('details', 'App\Services\NameAndRole')
{{ $details->username }}
{{ $details->slug }}
```

Comment: I'm assuming that this is [your question on Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/about-service-injection). This solution is good, as it only queries the database once in the constructor when the instance is created, and it stores them in the class properties so it doesn't need to query the database again. @Yurich's solution however, was calling the `nameAndRole()` method twice so it executed the same code again, including the `getRoles()` method, which I'm assuming is querying the database to fetch the roles, so it would of had queried the database twice.

Answer (score 0):

You should get variable from method

```
@inject('nameAndRole','App\Services\NameAndRole')
<div>
   <h4 >username：{{$nameAndRole->nameAndRole()['username']}}</h4>
   <h4>slug：{{$nameAndRole->nameAndRole()['slug']}}}</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code will have the effect the user expected the first time, it's a bad implementation as it unnecessarily makes two method calls and queries the database twice for the same information.

Comment: I just showed how to implement inject with this method.

Comment: I got that, but in this case **working suggestion** ≠ **good suggestion**.

Comment: I got an answer on laracasts.com,I think that's what I want.But, will it   query the database twice?  @Bogdan